# Text in the middle of a doughnut for charjs

Tags: yii2, chart.js

I everybody,

i use 2amigos/yii2-chartjs-widget in my project. Now i draw doughnuts with a text inside. It works fine, but if i display a legend on left or right side, the text is not in the middle of the doughnut.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prnzw.png)

My code:

```
                'plugins' =>
                    new \yii\web\JsExpression('
                    [{
                        id: \'text\',
                        afterDatasetsDraw: function(chart, a, b) {
                            var width = chart.width,
                            height = chart.height,
                            ctx=chart.ctx;
                            ctx.restore();
                            var fontSize = (height / 50).toFixed(2);
                            ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
                            ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
                            ctx.fillStyle ="rgb(200,200,200)";
                
                            var text = "'.$numVal.'",
                            textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
                            textY = height / 2;
                
                            ctx.fillText(text, textX, textY);
                            ctx.save();
                        }
                    }]')
```

I hope ones of you has a tip for me.

Thanks very much...

Comment: i've found a solution. Now i used chart.chartArea.right to set the widht instead chart.width. No it works...

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use the chart dom element size but the chart area.

```
[{
  id: 'text',
  afterDatasetsDraw: function(chart) {
    const {ctx, chartArea} = chart; 
    const {left, top, width, height} = chartArea;
    ctx.save();
    var fontSize = (height / 50).toFixed(2); // In my opinion this should be reevaluated
    ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
    ctx.fillStyle ="rgb(200,200,200)";
                
    var text = "'.$numVal.'",
      textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
      textY = height / 2;
                
    ctx.fillText(text, left + textX, top + textY);
    ctx.restore();
  }
}]
```

Comment: Sorry. But this solution not works. The doughnut is empty. There no errors shown in console. I still use var width = chart.chartArea.right to set the with and this work for me.

Comment: Here is a codepen https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/gOBjjjQ where the plugin is working